# Sql left join on left key with null values

Tags: sql, null, left-join

I have a question about join with key with null value.

Suppose I have a table `t`, which is going to be on left side. (`id` is primary key and `sub_id` is the key to join with the right table.)

```
    id sub_id value
    1  3       23
    2  3       234
    3  2       245
    4  1       12
    5  null    948
    6  2       45
    7  null    12
```

and I have another table `m` which is on right side. (`t.sub_id = m.id`)

```
    id feature
    1  9       
    2  8       
    3  2       
    4  1       
    5  4    
    6  2       
    7  null
```

Now I want to use

```
    select * from t left join m on t.sub_id = m.id
```

What result will it return? Is `Null` value in left key influence the result? I want all `null` left key rows not to shown in my result.

Thank you!

Comment: `I want all null left key rows not to shown in my result.` Then you don't want to be using a `LEFT JOIN`. A plain `JOIN` (inner join) would be appropriate here.

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` will include everything from the left table. I think you might want an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: You could test.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself rather than asking here???

Comment: Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A `left join` is quite simple.  It keeps all rows in the first (left) table plus all rows in the second (right) table, when the `on` clause evaluates to "true".

When the `on` clause evaluates to "false" or `NULL`, the `left join` still keeps all rows in the first table with `NULL` values for the second table.

If either `sub_id` or `id` is `NULL`, then your `on` clause evaluates to `NULL`, so it keeps all rows in the first table with `NULL` placeholders for the columns in the second.

Answer (score 2):

I think `inner join` is not a solution because there are keys in the `right` and he doesn't want to have it in the joined table. You can still do `left join` then add a statement to drop all `keys = null`

you can try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM t 
LEFT JOIN m ON t.sub_id = m.id
WHERE t.sub_id != NULL
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM t 
LEFT JOIN m ON t.sub_id = m.id  
WHERE t.sub_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You syntax is off. Either move the `LEFT JOIN ...` to the `FROM` clause or put the `SELECT ... WHERE ...` in a subquery, join to that and put an outer query around it. Whatever you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Left joins by definition will include all the ids from the left part of the join, no matter if the id has a valid mapping in the other table, if it has not it will be related to `NULL`.

If you want to use only valid links you need to use `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You will keep all the results from your Left table.
Have in mind if you have a null value on the Left table this (null) is not going to be evaluated [null = null is not a valid expression]

```
Left table
id value
1  1
2  null

Right table 
id value
1  1
2  1
3  null
4  null
```

Result from Left Join between Left and Right table using(value) as join key

```
Result table
id value id_1 value_1
1  1     1    1
1  1     2    1
2  null  null null
```